# If $a, d$ are relatively primes and $n$ is arbitrary given, then does there exist a number in $\{a+d, a+2d, ..., a+nd\}$ satisfying the condition?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions, coprime

If $a, d$ are relatively primes and $n$ is arbitrary given number, then does there exist a number in $\{a+d, a+2d, ..., a+nd\}$ which is relatively prime to any other number of $\{a+d, a+2d, ..., a+nd\}$?

I calculated a few cases with my bare hands, it seems to me true.

For sufficiently large $n$, by Dirichlet’s theorem, there must be a prime among $a+[\frac{n+1}{2}]d, ..., a+nd$, so this is true.

But I’d like to see whether it is true for any given $n$.

Could you tell me this is true or not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Won't Bertrand's postulate help?

Comment: the first one divisible by another is a+(a+d+1)d

Comment: Or you could proceed by way of contradiction.Try to get a contradiction by assuming that for some $n_0$ there exists no such number in {$a+d , a+2d,...,a+n_o d$} that is relatively prime to any other in the set.

Comment: @glimpser, the point is if it's not true, you'll come to a contradictory result of the axioms or definitions or theorems your logic system has.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yes, I misunderstood it.

Comment: another pointer if a and d are non-zero modulo a value r, we can show one of the first r values divide by r, and every r-th after that.

Comment: doh nondivisors as well.

Comment: If $a+md$ and $a+nd$ share a factor $f$ so does their difference $d(n-m)$.  Any factor of $d$ is not a factor of $a+nd$, so $f|n-m$.

Comment: @Empy2 Yes, I've seen this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the question to ask that none of them is coprime to all the rest - that there is at least one partner for each.

This is a list of $26$ numbers from $a+d$ to $a+26d$, which all share factors.
Suppose $a+d$ is a multiple of $2,5,11$ and $17$.
Suppose $a+2d$ is a multiple of $3$.
Suppose $a+3d$ is a multiple of $7$ and $19$.
Suppose $a+4d$ is a multiple of $13$.
Then $a+kd$ are all even for all odd $k$.
$a+2d,a+8d,a+14d,a+20d,a+26d$ are multiples of $3$.
$a+4d,a+17d$ are multiples of $13$.
$a+6d,a+16d$ are multiples of $5$.
$a+10d,a+24d$ are multiples of $7$.
$a+12d,a+d$ are multiples of $11$.
$a+18d,a+d$ are multiples of $17$.
$a+3d,a+22d$ are multiples of $19$.

Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find $a,d$ coprime to each other and to the primes less than twenty to set this up.

$$713+6767*[1:26]$$

Comment: It seems to me this contradicts to@GregMartin's answer. Which is right? Or are you dealing with different question?

Comment: He took it that no pair is coprime.  I took it that no term is entirely coprime to the rest.

Comment: So I think that he showed that for each number, there always exists a number coprime to given number. But you showed that there exists a case in which any term can't be coprime to the rest of numbers. Is it right?

Comment: That's how I understand it

Comment: Then the actual intention to my question was related to your answer. I wanna see whether there exists a number coprime to the rest of numbers, not just coprime to one of the rest.

Comment: But we have to see such a list of numbers is possible to exist.